# Why is my program with pthreads taking longer than the sequential one

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, qnx

I'm relatively new to multithread programming. I wrote a program which is calculating the squares from 0 - 10000 and saving them into an array. The sequential program is running much faster than the parallel. In my parallel program I have divided  the loop into 8 threads (my machine has 8 cores) but it is much slower! Anyone an idea why this is the case? I have added the screenshots of the execution times.

```
/*Here is the normal program:*/

#define ARRAYSIZE 10000

int main(void) {

    int array[ARRAYSIZE];

    int i;

    for (i=0; i<ARRAYSIZE; i++)
    {
        array[i]=i*i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

```
/*Here is the parallelized calculation. Used from http://ramcdougal.com/threads.html*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE 10000
#define NUMTHREADS 8  /*Cause have 8 core on my machine*/

struct ThreadData {
    int start;
    int stop;
    int* array;
};

void* squarer (struct ThreadData* td);

/* puts i^2 into array positions i=start to stop-1 */
void* squarer (struct ThreadData* td)
{
    struct ThreadData* data = (struct ThreadData*) td;
    int start=data->start;
    int stop=data->stop;
    int* array=data->array;
    int i;
    for(i= start; i<stop; i++)
    {
        array[i]=i*i;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {

int array[ARRAYSIZE];
pthread_t thread[NUMTHREADS];
struct ThreadData data[NUMTHREADS];
int i;

int tasksPerThread= (ARRAYSIZE + NUMTHREADS - 1)/ NUMTHREADS;

/* Divide work for threads, prepare parameters */
/* This means in my example I divide the loop into 8 regions: 0 ..1250,1250 .. 2500 etc., 2500 .. 3750 */

for(i=0; i<NUMTHREADS;i++)
{
    data[i].start=i*tasksPerThread;
    data[i].stop=(i+1)*tasksPerThread;
    data[i].array=array;

    data[NUMTHREADS-1].stop=ARRAYSIZE;
}

for(i=0; i<NUMTHREADS;i++)
{
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, squarer, &data[i]);
}

for(i=0; i<NUMTHREADS;i++)
{
    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
}

return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: There is overhead for threading and the threads are not necessarily executed on different cores.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but I believe the task is too simple. You are dealing with microsecond tasks on a complete task that, in serial, takes a few microseconds. The overhead of the threading is just too large here. If you make the task a bit more computationally challenging, you will see results.

Comment: You need to specify how you compile this, with what compiler and options. Because your whole main() is one big no-op and any half decent compiler from around year 1995 or later or so will optimize away this whole program...

Comment: And note that some 95% of all "strange performance" questions on SO can be explained by the OP using wrong compiler settings or wrong benchmarking methods. Rarely ever by the code itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to have a garden party. In preparation, you must move 8 chairs from the house into the garden. You call a moving company and ask them to send 8 movers. They arrive from across town and quickly complete the task, one chair each. The 8 movers drive back to the other end of the town. When they return, they call you and tell you that the task has been completed.

Question: Would the whole process have gone faster if you had moved the 8 chairs yourself?

Answer: Yes, the actual task (moving 8 chairs a short distance) is far too small to involve a moving company. The time spent on transport back and forth far exceeds the time spent on the task itself.

The example above is similar to what your code does.

Starting 8 threads is equivalent to driving from the other end of town to your house.

Stopping 8 threads is equivalent to returning back.

There is far too much wasted time compared to the size of the task to be solved.

Lesson: Only use multi-threading when the task is sufficiently big.

So for your test, you should increase `ARRAYSIZE` (a lot). Further, you have to add some code that prevents the compiler from doing optimizations that bypass the array assignments.

Try the code below (It's OPs code with a few changes).

**Single thread**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE 1000000000
unsigned array[ARRAYSIZE];


int main(void) {

    unsigned i;

    for (i=0; i<ARRAYSIZE; i++)
    {
        array[i]=i*i;
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    return array[rand() % ARRAYSIZE] > 10000;
}
```

My result: 1.169 s

**Multi thread**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE 1000000000
unsigned array[ARRAYSIZE];
#define NUMTHREADS 8  /*Cause have 8 core on my machine*/

struct ThreadData {
    unsigned start;
    unsigned stop;
    unsigned* array;
};


/* puts i^2 into array positions i=start to stop-1 */
void* squarer (void* td)
{
    struct ThreadData* data = (struct ThreadData*) td;
    unsigned start=data->start;
    unsigned stop=data->stop;
    unsigned* array=data->array;
    unsigned i;
    for(i= start; i<stop; i++)
    {
        array[i]=i*i;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
  pthread_t thread[NUMTHREADS];
  struct ThreadData data[NUMTHREADS];
  int i;

  int tasksPerThread= (ARRAYSIZE + NUMTHREADS - 1)/ NUMTHREADS;

/* Divide work for threads, prepare parameters */
/* This means in my example I divide the loop into 8 regions: 0 ..1250,1250 .. 2500 etc., 2500 .. 3750 */

  for(i=0; i<NUMTHREADS;i++)
  {
    data[i].start=i*tasksPerThread;
    data[i].stop=(i+1)*tasksPerThread;
    data[i].array=array;

    data[NUMTHREADS-1].stop=ARRAYSIZE;
  }

  for(i=0; i<NUMTHREADS;i++)
  {
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, squarer, &data[i]);
  }

  for(i=0; i<NUMTHREADS;i++)
  {
    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
  }

  srand(time(NULL));
  return array[rand() % ARRAYSIZE] > 10000;
}
```

My result: 0.192 s

Comment: Well explained! Understood the problem. There is a point of complexity where threads make sense and where not.